# Кастомная обработка исключений .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

В проекте ASP.Net Core MVC необходимо реализовать обработку исключений. В зависимости от возникшего исключения выводить ту или иную информацию. Нашёл, что это делается при помощи `UseExceptionHandler`, привёл свой Startup.cs к виду:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Service/Error");
  var timeout = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.GetSection("SessionSettings")["IdleTimeout"] ?? "60");
  app.UseSession(new SessionOptions
  {
    IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout)
  });
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {
    routes.MapRoute("default","{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
}
```

но, при возникновении исключения (например ошибка подключения к БД), браузер демонстрирует стандартную ошибку 500 и в метод `ServiceController.Error` переходить никто не собирается

Comment: попробуй переместить вызов `app.UseExceptionHandler(...)` перед непосредственно перед вызовом `app.UseMvc(...)`

Comment: @Grundy, результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пометить ваш Error action атрибутом [Route("/Service/Error")]

Comment: Результат нулевой

Comment: Я использую вот такую штуку:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kim0sFPX